# Is it possible in Javascript to have a waiting animation while retrieving from localStorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Understanding that the Javascript localStorage API is synchronous and thus blocking, is there any workaround that would allow one to display a waiting animation that doesn't freeze during the `getItem()`  or `setItem()` operations?

Comment: start animation before storage operation. do storage operation(s). stop animation?

Comment: At least the way I've tried it, the animation freezes during the storage operation.

Comment: What kind of storage are you talking about then? Simply using `localStorage.setItem()`? Is it a large amount of data? Do you have to serialize it? Are you doing something separate that is synchronous that blocks the page?

Comment: Yes, very simple calls to localStorage.setItem() and getItem(). Yes, serialization is necessary. It's probably ~300kb of data. I can't think of anything else that would be blocking, except possibly the JSON.parse() call when deserializing.

Comment: What type of animation did you use, a javascripted one? You could try CSS animations or animated GIFs, which might run in a separate thread (depending on browser though).

Comment: It was jQuery Mobile's $.mobile.loading.show()  but I'm certainly not committed to that option.

Comment: @MarcB Unfortunately, accessing `localStorage` freezes the UI, just like a synchronous Ajax call (or, really, any long-running synchronous job).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If getting 300kB of data from local storage and parsing it with `JSON.parse` is too slow for a single synchronous blocking operation, you will have to split it up in smaller chunks. Those can be stored in single storage slots and shell be processed in an [asynchronous loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4288759/1048572) (see also [JavaScript Performance Long Running Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6864397/1048572), [How to stop intense Javascript loop from freezing the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/714942/1048572)).

Answer (score 3):

You can make any synchronous operation, including localStorage, asynchronous by using [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers).

Comment: Web Workers look like they might have promise! Any experience with using them in a mobile app (e.g. Phonegap/Cordova) environment?

Comment: I'm not a mobile developer so I couldn't say. However, [not all mobile browsers seem to support them](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers), so if it's using the browser under the hood that might be a problem on some platforms.