# run a function once previous function complete

Tags: angularjs

In the success callback to an ajax query, I have to

```
a) update the property of an object in an array (and I have to locate that object in the array)
b) save that array again in storage 
c) broadcast an event
```

I'm (trying to) accomplishing that by doing this (code below)

```
updateTheArray(myarray,'date', $scope.date);
myStorage.put(myarray);
$scope.$broadcast('alldone');
```

As I'm concerned these are happening out of order or could happen out of order,I would like to be able to do something like (in pseudo code) in the success callback

```
 var updated = updateTheArray();  //update a property on an object in array
 updated.promise().then(function(){
     myStorage.put(array);  //saves
  }).done(function(){
     $scope.$broadcast('alldone'); //broadcast
 }
```

However, the way I've written the storage and the updateTheArray function are not setup to do that.

Is there a way in Angular to make sure the next function only runs once the first one is complete?

Leaving aside the updateTheArray function, even if I try to use the storage function in promise like this

```
   var save = myStorage.put(array);
    save.promise().done(function(){
       console.log('blah');
    });
```

I get a `cannot read property promise of undefined` error, so how do I make that storage return a promise object?

**updateTheArray (finds a particular object in an array and changes a property)**

```
function updateTheArray(array, attr, value){
   var len = array.length;
   len = len -1;
   for (var i = len; i > 0; i --){
      if(array[i][attr] === value) { //find by date
         array[i]['completed'] = true; //set some property to true
      }
   }
}
```

**storage**

```
app.factory('myStorage', function(){
      return {

            get: function(){
                   return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_ID) || '[]');
             },
            put: function(myarray){
                   localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_ID, JSON.stringify(myarray));
             }

       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20231180/789529), local storage calls are synchronous, so there is no need to wait for myStorage.put to complete.

The reason for the `cannot read property promise of undefined` error is that you aren't returning anything at all from your put function on myStorage (but, as above, you don't need to return a promise anyway as it's a synchronous call).

The `updateTheArray` implementation you have shown is also synchronous, so the whole thing should work in order as-is, without any callbacks or promises required.