# How to clear localstorage data in ionic?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

Here is my code.

```
$scope.logout=function(){
    localstorage.set('user_id', "");
    localstorage.set('access-token', "");
    localstorage.set('isUserTraverseColony', 0);
    localstorage.set('isStarted', 0);
    $window.localStorage.clear();
    $window.localStorage.removeItem(access-token);
    $ionicHistory.clearCache();
    $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
 };
```

I want to delete the access-token variable from my localStorage, It working fine for browser when i use

```
 $window.localStorage.clear();
 $window.localStorage.removeItem(access-token);
```

But its not working for my App.

here is my localstorage factory

```
angular.module('starter.controllers').factory('localstorage', ['$window', '$localStorage','$q', function ($window, $localStorage,$q) {
    return {
        set: function (key, value) {
             var deferred = $q.defer();
            $window.localStorage[key] = value;
                 deferred.resolve(1);
                 return deferred.promise;
        },
        get: function (key, defaultValue) {
            return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
        },
        setObject: function (key, value) {
            $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
        },
        getObject: function (key) {
            return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || '{}');
        }
    }

}]);
```

Any Idea?

Comment: 'access-tokan' is a typo or you have it like this in your code? Have you tried using `localstorage.clear()` (remove `$window`)?

Comment: I am using local storage factory,  i have edited my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had also faced same problem mean time ago.  I was using some **Global variable for Local Storage**. 
Your code seems ok. But  you can optimize it better

```
$scope.logout = function(){
  $window.localStorage.clear();
    $ionicHistory.clearCache();
    $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
 };
```

You don't need to set

```
localstorage.set('user_id', "");
localstorage.set('access-token', "");
localstorage.set('isUserTraverseColony', 0);
localstorage.set('isStarted', 0);
```

because you are clearing them.

Answer (score 4):

You could add the `clear()` method to your custom `localstorage` service:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers').factory('localstorage', ['$window', '$localStorage','$q', function ($window, $localStorage,$q) {
    return {
        set: function (key, value) {
            $window.localStorage.setItem(key, value);
        },
        get: function (key, defaultValue) {
            return $window.localStorage.getItem(key) || defaultValue;
        },
        setObject: function (key, value) {
            $window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
        },
        getObject: function (key) {
            return JSON.parse($window.localStorage.getItem(key) || '{}');
        },
        clear: function () {
            $window.localStorage.clear();
        }
    }

}]);
```

**Note: I updated your service removing promise because [HTML5 localStorage is syncronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20231163/is-html5-localstorage-asynchronous) and using standard get and set methods**

And then in you controller:

```
$scope.logout = function(){
    localstorage.clear();
    $ionicHistory.clearCache();
    $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
 };
```