# Using shouldComponentUpdate for block component re-render every second

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-dnd

That game developed with react and redux.I am not react-redux developer(I am .net developer) but I must continue that project so I am new in react and redux
    That game performance is too bad in some android phones.So I analyze project.I see that components render method works every second.My component contain more than 30 other components.So every secon it re render and this is cause bad performance in some old android phones

Why React component re render every second?Can I block this?
I search for that problem I see that solution is shouldComponentUpdate function

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps,nextState) {

        console.log(nextProps.gameStore.get('state'));//waiting
        console.log(this.props.gameStore.get('state'));//waiting

        console.log(this.state);
        console.log(nextState);
        if (nextProps.gameStore.get('state')==this.props.gameStore.get('state')) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
        }
```

but in this function nextstate and this state is same,
nextProps.gameStore.get('state') and this.props.gameStore.get('state') is the same.Why next state and current state is same?What should I do?I use constructor but it is still same here is all my component code

```
    import React from 'react';
import { DragDropContext } from 'react-dnd';
import HTML5Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';
//import { default as HTML5Backend } from 'react-dnd-touch-backend';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { bindFirstArguments } from 'utils/bindFirstArgument';
import * as OkeyGameActions from 'actions/OkeyGameActions';
import * as OkeyNetActions from 'actions/OkeyNetActions';

import * as OkeyChatActions from 'actions/Chatactions';

import { SeatDirection } from 'constants/AppConstants';

import { OkeyScoreboardDialog }
from 'components/OkeyScoreboardDialog/OkeyScoreboardDialog';
import OkeyMatchResultDialog
from 'components/OkeyMatchResultDialog/OkeyMatchResultDialog';

import OkeyRackWrapper from 'components/OkeyRackWrapper/OkeyRackWrapper';
import OkeyTopToolbar from 'components/OkeyTopToolbar/OkeyTopToolbar';
import OkeyTableToolbar from 'components/OkeyTableToolbar/OkeyTableToolbar';
import OkeyTableCenter from 'components/OkeyTableCenter/OkeyTableCenter';

import CustomDragLayer from 'components/CustomDragLayer/CustomDragLayer';
import MessageList from 'components/chat/MessageList';
import PrivateEastMessageList from 'components/chat/PrivateEastMessageList';
import PrivateNorthMessageList from 'components/chat/PrivateNorthMessageList';
import PrivateWestMessageList from 'components/chat/PrivateWestMessageList';
import PrivateSouthMessageList from 'components/chat/PrivateSouthMessageList';

import './_OkeyGame.scss';

function toJS(item) {
  if (item === null) {
    return null;
  }
  //var item1=item.toJS();
  //if (item1.color==='BLACK') {
  //    var a='a';
    //}

  if (item == undefined) {
      return;
  }

  return item.toJS();
}

function getRelativeDirection(selfSeat, direction) {
  let relativeDirection = direction;

  if (selfSeat >= 0) {
    relativeDirection = (selfSeat - direction + 4) % 4;
  }
  return relativeDirection;
}

class OkeyGame extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
  super(props);
    }





    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps,nextState) {

        console.log(nextProps.gameStore.get('state'));//waiting
        console.log(this.props.gameStore.get('state'));//waiting

        console.log(this.state);
        console.log(nextState);
        if (nextProps.gameStore.get('state')==this.props.gameStore.get('state')) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
        }
    render() {

    const { dispatch, gameStore, gamePlay, playRules } = this.props;

    let actions = bindActionCreators(OkeyGameActions, dispatch);

    let netActions = bindActionCreators(OkeyNetActions, dispatch);
    const currentTurn = gameStore.get('currentTurn');

    const playState = {
      selectedStone: gamePlay.get('selectedStone'),
      gosterge: gamePlay.get('gosterge'),
      middleStoneCount: gamePlay.get('middleStoneCount'),
      currentTurn: currentTurn
    };


    if (playState.gosterge != undefined) {
        window.localStorage.setItem('gostergeNumber', playState.gosterge._root.entries[0][1]);
        window.localStorage.setItem('gostergeColor', playState.gosterge._root.entries[1][1]);
    }


    const hasOpenedStonesThisTurn = {
      hasOpenedSequenceThisTurn: playRules.get('hasOpenedSequenceThisTurn'),
      hasOpenedPairsThisTurn: playRules.get('hasOpenedPairsThisTurn')
    };

    const rules = {
      canOpenSequence: playRules.get('canOpenSequence'),
      canOpenPairs: playRules.get('canOpenPairs'),
      canWithdraw: playRules.get('canWithdraw'),
      canDiscard: playRules.get('canDiscard'),
      canCollectOpen: playRules.get('canCollectOpen'),
      canLeaveTaken: playRules.get('canLeaveTaken'),
      canProcessStone: playRules.get('canProcessStone')
    };

    const discardMiniBoxes = {
      discardMiniBoxPairs: gamePlay.get('pairs'),
      discardMiniBoxSequence: gamePlay.get('sequence')
    };

    const selfSeat = gameStore.get('selfSeat');

    const { westSeat, eastSeat, northSeat, southSeat } =
    {
      westSeat: getRelativeDirection(selfSeat, SeatDirection.WEST),
      eastSeat: getRelativeDirection(selfSeat, SeatDirection.EAST),
      northSeat: getRelativeDirection(selfSeat, SeatDirection.NORTH),
      southSeat: getRelativeDirection(selfSeat, SeatDirection.SOUTH)
};

    const players = {
      selfSeat: selfSeat,
      pSouth: {
        seatId: southSeat,
        discardStones: gamePlay.getIn(['discardStones', southSeat]),
        profile: toJS(gameStore.getIn(['players', southSeat])),
        dispatch: dispatch
      },
      pNorth: {
        seatId: northSeat,
        discardStones: gamePlay.getIn(['discardStones', northSeat]),
        profile: toJS(gameStore.getIn(['players', northSeat])),
        dispatch: dispatch
      },
      pEast: {
        seatId: eastSeat,
        discardStones: gamePlay.getIn(['discardStones', eastSeat]),
        profile: toJS(gameStore.getIn(['players', eastSeat])),
        dispatch: dispatch
      },
      pWest: {
        seatId: westSeat,
        discardStones: gamePlay.getIn(['discardStones', westSeat]),
        profile: toJS(gameStore.getIn(['players', westSeat])),
        dispatch: dispatch
      }
    };


    let profiles = [
              players.pSouth.profile,
              players.pEast.profile,
              players.pNorth.profile,
              players.pWest.profile
    ];

    localStorage.setItem("selfSeat", selfSeat);
    localStorage.setItem("roomID", gameStore.get('id'));

    if (selfSeat == 0) 
        profiles = [players.pSouth.profile,players.pEast.profile,players.pNorth.profile,players.pWest.profile];

    else if (selfSeat == 1) 
        profiles = [players.pWest.profile,players.pSouth.profile,players.pEast.profile,players.pNorth.profile];

    else if (selfSeat == 2) 
        profiles = [players.pNorth.profile,players.pWest.profile,players.pSouth.profile,players.pEast.profile];

    else if (selfSeat == 3) 
        profiles = [players.pEast.profile,players.pNorth.profile,players.pWest.profile,players.pSouth.profile];


    const matchState = {
      name: gameStore.getIn(['options', 'name']),
      maxRounds: gameStore.getIn(['options', 'rounds']),
      stake: gameStore.getIn(['options', 'stakes']),
      round: gameStore.get('round')
    };



    const owner = gamePlay.get('ownerID');

    const scoreboard = gameStore.get('scoreboard');

    const matchResult = gameStore.get('matchResult');

    const restCountdown = gameStore.get('restCountdown');

    const roomState = gameStore.get('roomState');



const { messageList } = this.props;
const { privateEastMessageList } = this.props;
const { privateNorthMessageList } = this.props;
const { privateWestMessageList } = this.props;
const { privateSouthMessageList } = this.props;

let chatActions = bindActionCreators(OkeyChatActions, dispatch);
// const  dispatch1  = this.props

    // each action has a first argument of room id
netActions = bindFirstArguments(netActions, gameStore.get('id'));

    let from = gameStore.get('from');
    let to = gameStore.get('to');
    let gift = gameStore.get('gift');

    let from1 = gameStore.get('from1');
    let to1 = gameStore.get('to1');
    let gift1 = gameStore.get('gift1');

    let from2 = gameStore.get('from2');
    let to2 = gameStore.get('to2');
    let gift2 = gameStore.get('gift2');

    let from3 = gameStore.get('from3');
    let to3 = gameStore.get('to3');
    let gift3 = gameStore.get('gift3');

    let arayan = gameStore.get('arayan');
    let aranan = gameStore.get('aranan');

    return (
        <div className="game-background" style={{background: 'url(http://okey101.xyz/staticImg/background.png)',backgroundSize:'cover'}}>
      <div className="okey-game flex-centered-column">
       <CustomDragLayer isMini={gamePlay.get('isOver') > 0}></CustomDragLayer>


        <MessageList {...chatActions} {...netActions} messageList={messageList} />

             <OkeyScoreboardDialog profiles={profiles}
      scoreboard={scoreboard} />


        <OkeyMatchResultDialog matchResult={matchResult}
        {...netActions}
        {...actions}
        roomState={roomState}/>


        <OkeyTopToolbar {...netActions}
                        {...matchState}
                        profiles={profiles}/>

        <OkeyTableCenter {...actions}
                         {...netActions}
                         {...playState}
                         {...rules}
                         {...discardMiniBoxes}
                         {...players}
                         owner={owner}
                         messageList={messageList}
                         privateEastMessageList={privateEastMessageList}
                         privateNorthMessageList={privateNorthMessageList}
                         privateWestMessageList={privateWestMessageList}
                         privateSouthMessageList={privateSouthMessageList}
                         from={from} 
                         to={to}
                         gift={gift}
                         from1={from1} 
                         to1={to1}
                         gift1={gift1}
                         from2={from2} 
                         to2={to2}
                         gift2={gift2}
                         from3={from3} 
                         to3={to3}
                         gift3={gift3}
                         arayan={arayan}
                         aranan={aranan}
                         stones={gamePlay.get('stones')}/>

        <OkeyRackWrapper {...actions}
                         {...netActions}
                         {...playState}
                         stones={gamePlay.get('stones')}
                         stoneGroups={gamePlay.get('stoneGroups')}/>
        <OkeyTableToolbar {...actions}
                          {...netActions}
                          {...rules}
                          restCountdown={restCountdown}
                          currentTurn={currentTurn}
                          {...hasOpenedStonesThisTurn}
                          roomState={roomState}
                          stones={gamePlay.get('stones')}
                          {...discardMiniBoxes}
                          okeyStone={gamePlay.get('okeyStone')}/>

      </div>

</div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state => ({
  gameStore: state.gameStore,
  gamePlay: state.gamePlay,
  playRules: state.playRules,
  messageList: state.MessageList,
  privateEastMessageList: state.PrivateEastMessageList,
  privateNorthMessageList: state.PrivateNorthMessageList,
  privateWestMessageList: state.PrivateWestMessageList,
  privateSouthMessageList: state.PrivateSouthMessageList
}));

const OkeyGameWithDnD = DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(OkeyGame);

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(OkeyGameWithDnD);
```

Edit:With  Aftab Khan directives I change component to PureComponent but the page does not open and there is not error in console

I change this to

```
const mapStateToProps = (state => ({
    gameStore: toJS(state.gameStore),
    gamePlay: toJS(state.gamePlay),
    playRules: toJS(state.playRules),
    messageList: toJS(state.MessageList),
    privateEastMessageList: toJS(state.PrivateEastMessageList),
    privateNorthMessageList: toJS(state.PrivateNorthMessageList),
    privateWestMessageList: toJS(state.PrivateWestMessageList),
    privateSouthMessageList: toJS(state.PrivateSouthMessageList)
}));
```

but it still does not work
then I change it to this

```
const mapStateToProps = (state => ({
    gameStore: state.gameStore.toJS(),
    gamePlay: state.gamePlay.toJS(),
    playRules: state.playRules.toJS(),
    messageList: state.MessageList.toJS(),
    privateEastMessageList: state.PrivateEastMessageList.toJS(),
    privateNorthMessageList: state.PrivateNorthMessageList.toJS(),
    privateWestMessageList: state.PrivateWestMessageList.toJS(),
    privateSouthMessageList: state.PrivateSouthMessageList.toJS()
}));
```

but it still does not open in browser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are few things I noticed about your component

1. `render` method does all lot of initialization for the children components
2. `shouldComponentUpdate` is unnecessary as it deals only with props (which is expected as all your state is in the redux store).
3. PureComponent is unnecessary to given that you are connecting it to the store using `connect()`. Your component has not state, its better being and functional [components created using a simple es6 arrow function](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components)

For 2. and 3. refer the [note](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#implementing-container-components) on optimizations `connect()` does for you as it creates containers.

Now its impossible to tell you why your components are being rendered every second without inspecting every line of your components. However, with carefully consideration of the following can help you make sure re-renders are triggered frugally and only when necessary.

**1. Keep `render()` method as light-weight as possible**
`render` is probably the most called method in all components. More bloated it is slow will you render cycles be. You can move all you `localStorage.setItems` to `componentWillReceiveProps`. Each one of those [synchronous LocalStorage calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20231163/is-html5-localstorage-asynchronous) is taking up render time.

**2. Remove `shouldComponentUpdate`. Instead pass only those props to components that it absolutely requires. Make as many components stateless pure functions**

shouldComponentUpdate is an escape hatch for components that take in more props they need to render.  Downside of sCU: it runs before every component re-render. In some cases it can slow down instead of speeding things up. See this comment [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5677#issuecomment-165125151) by jimfb. This supports my suggestion of turning as many components into stateless function components as you can - including maybe the component you posted here

**3. PureComponent will not be needed if your components are stateless javascript functions taking in only the props they need.**

Comment: @user1688401 Feel free to comment with more details so that we can understand your problem better.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need `React.PureComponent`.
Here is the link to it. [Link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.purecomponentx)

Basically what it does is before rendering each component, it will check if the component has any changes in the props or the state. If there is no change it won't reRender.

Looks like you are using immutable data structures in your reducer. In ur mapStateToProps, change all the immutable data to normal JS objects calling `toJS()` method. Then PureComponent will work as intended.

Comment: if I use PureComponent should I use any shallowCompare or it will do that compare check automatically? And for PureComponent should I install any npm package or just change pureComponent like this?  class OkeyGame extends React.PureComponent

Comment: Instead of saying `class OkeyGame extends React.Component`
You use `class OkeyGame extends React.PureComponent`

You don't need any extra package. It compares the root level attributes shallowly before allowing to re-render

Comment: it does not work.Should I change all my components or sub components  to react.PureComponent?

Comment: Seems like you have immutable data directly passed inside ur component. In ur mapStateToProps, change all the immutable data to normal JS objects calling `toJS()` method. Then PureComponent will start working as intended

Comment: Updating this in the answer as well

Comment: I change item to item.toJS() but it still does not open in browser.I Update question...this is my mapstatetoproops     const mapStateToProps = (state => ({
    gameStore: state.gameStore.toJS(),
    gamePlay: state.gamePlay.toJS(),
    playRules: state.playRules.toJS(),
    messageList: state.MessageList.toJS(),
    privateEastMessageList: state.PrivateEastMessageList.toJS(),
    privateNorthMessageList: state.PrivateNorthMessageList.toJS(),
 
}));

Comment: I will update this is answer but it does not work.I edited question you can see my editing at the below question,thanks

Comment: @user1688401 You should not be calling `toJS()` inside of your mapStateToProps function. `toJS` will return a new object reference every time it is called which will cause your render function to run again. Instead your should try using component's own state to hold an instance of your mutable prop data. When `componentDidMount` or `componentWillReceiveProps` you can call `toJS()` on the next props and save the result in `this.setState(resultOfToJS)`

Comment: @user1688401 Be aware that PureComponents only do a shallow comparison of props meaning that `a !== b` but it will not do `a.1 !== b.1` so  the result maybe that your parent component will not re-render children. I would go with what @manas-jayanth recommended instead. In order to get performant UI in React you need to keep your components as pure functions and move your state management to a single component some where higher in the chain.