# connect multiple combined reducers in redux with conditional

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have an app that have different access level, like admin, guest and normal user, so it has several roles. My folder structure is very clear, some components are shared like Button, Loader but reducers and actions are not shared, because they are completely different of apps.

I did this to do conditioning setting for my store (Yes I only need one store because the entry for all type of the user is the same)

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { getUserRole } from './utils' // merely localstorage util to get roles
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'

import userReducers from './reducers'
import adminReducers from './reducers/admin'

//share reducer btw member and admin
let reducers
if (getUserRole() === 'member') {
  reducers = userReducers
} else {
  reducers = adminReducers
}

console.log('reducers', reducers) //undefined during the first load, most likely store is done setup before localstorage?

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  )
)
export default store
```

The problem is reducers is `undefined` unless I refresh the entire page.

Comment: add `getUserRole()` code

Comment: @kiarashws a function that has this function body`localstorage.get('token').decode('role')` that's about it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is that `localStore` is not async according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20231180/5421321).

So by returning a `Promise` you'll make sure `getUserRole()` is not `undefined`:

```
export function getUserRole(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         let role = localStorage.getItem('token').decode('role')
         resolve(role)
    })
}
```

and in `index.js`:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { getUserRole } from './utils' // merely localstorage util to get roles
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'

import userReducers from './reducers'
import adminReducers from './reducers/admin'

//share reducer btw member and admin
let store
getUserRole().then(role => {
   reducers =  role === 'member'
   ? userReducers
   : adminReducers
   console.log('reducers', reducers) 
   store =  createStore(
       reducers,
       composeWithDevTools(
           applyMiddleware(thunk)
       )
   )
})

export default store
```

Tell me if something went wrong.

Comment: I got this error `Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Auth)". `https://pastebin.com/CfDPJh0T

Comment: What did you change? I don't see the changes

Comment: changed `localstorage.get('token').decode('role')` to `localStorage.getItem('token').decode('role')`

Comment: there is no problem at the async part just that it won't work like you did, I still got `Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Auth)" ` because `<Provider>` can't wait for the store.

Comment: you can try to create a demo and you will see the issue.