# load only works after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html

I made a "save and load" function for my incremental game.

They both work, but when I load the data, I have to click a button to "update" the values. This is not a problem with the main currency (scrap), but the problem is with the variables collector,collectorCost,drone and droneCost.

Both the parts have the same code, so I don't understand why it shouldn't be updated automatically.

The "save and load" functions are called when clicking a button

I don't know if i need to show more code.
I'm kind of new to this whole scene :).

Edit: Tried *load()* on page load but that doesn't change anything.

```html
<button onclick="save()">Save Game</button>
<button onclick="load()">Load Game</button>
```

```
function save(){
  var save = {
    scrap: scrap,
    collector: collector,
    collectorCost: collectorCost,
    drone: drone,
    droneCost: droneCost
  };
  localStorage.setItem("save",JSON.stringify(save));
};

function load(){
  var savegame = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("save"));
  if(typeof savegame.scrap !== "undefined") scrap = savegame.scrap;
  if(typeof savegame.collector !== "undefined") collector = savegame.collector;
  if(typeof savegame.collectorCost !== "undefined") collectorCost = savegame.collectorCost;
  if(typeof savegame.drone !== "undifined") drone = savegame.drone;
  if(typeof savegame.droneCost !== "undifined") droneCost = savegame.droneCost;
};
```

I expect the numbers to be updated automatically, which is for the main currency but not for: *collector*, *collectorCost*, *drone* and *droneCost*.

They only change after that I click the button to buy any of them

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: I tried to fix the spelling of the question, but I didn't understand what you mean with `but its happening to the parts that you buy`, can you rephrase it?

Comment: maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20231163/is-html5-localstorage-asynchronous

Comment: It sounds like you just need to call the `load()` function when the page first loads.

Comment: @h1b9b how does that help? If it were asynchronous it could be a problem, but that question says it isn't.

Comment: @Barmar the spec doesn't say if it sync or async, the second answer on that question get into the details of it

Comment: @h1b9b It ends with **The last sentence mandates that scripts accessing the same storage object are required to see things synchronously.**

Comment: @Barmar the answer was edited in 2016 and all the recent comment on that question experience the same behavior

Comment: @Thijmen_I if you already on save have the new values why load them from the localstorage ?

Comment: i dont have it saving/loading automaticly. i thought i had to have a separated button for saving to string the data and put it in local storage. and after that when i want to play again after closing the game i load it via the load game button

Comment: There are no errors in the javascript.

Comment: tried to call *load()* on page load but that doesnt change anything

Comment: Are you positive that the data actually ends up correctly in the localstorage when the game is saved? I’m guessing that the variables that aren’t restored are actually undefined there.

Comment: well, i guess it is correctly stored, because when i do click on of the buttons the variables do update to their correct values.

Comment: Please provide more context on how the functions are called. If there is more code inside `save()` and `load()`, please also show that.

Comment: added the html part how i call the functions *save()* and *load()*
and there is no more code inside *save()* and *load()*

Comment: “I expect the numbers to be updated automatically […] They only change after that I click the button to buy any of them.” Could it be that the issue is in the UI? If you *inspect* the variables after the load, by using `console.log` or the browser’s debugger, are they what you expect? Is it only the *display* that is not updated?

Comment: after i inspect the elements it indeed looks like it is the UI.. the elements do update when inspected.
how would i go about updating the UI when the load() function happens?

Comment: This is impossible to say without knowing how your UI code works. How do you reflect the changes in the UI when the player buys the items? You need to trigger that logic in your `load` function, too. Likewise you might check what part of your code causes the update in the currency display.

Comment: so i guess im a bit late :) but i found the problem, in a function i was calling some data where there was none.
nonetheless thanks guys