# Making sure that a value is saved in localStorage before redirecting

Tags: javascript, redirect, local-storage, settimeout

I want to store something in **localStorage** before redirecting the user to login page. The problem is that the browser doesn't always write the **localStorage** to the disk before i redirect to another page. So after the user gets redirected back to app from login page the value is undefined.

Is there a better way than using a **setTimeout** to make sure that a value is actually stored in **localStorage**?

Example:

```
localStorage.setItem("codeVerifier", codeVerifier);
window.location.href = "someLoginUrl";
```

Comment: Can you show a working example of the issue?  The operation to set a value in localstorage is not an asynchronous operation.  Once that method is done, the value should exist in storage.

Comment: Keeping in mind that this will not be true if the user is running their browser in a mode that disallows localstorage all together.

Comment: AFAIK, writing to localStorage is synchronous, so I doubt your assessment of the problem is correct.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20231163/is-html5-localstorage-asynchronous

Comment: @Barmar Already know that. That has nothing to do with when browser decides to write it to disk. I'm looking for a way the make sure it does. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Taplar added a simple sample in the question

Comment: Since it's synchronous, it will have been written when `localStorage.setItem()` returns.

Comment: You don't have to do anything to "make sure" -- it's already guaranteed.

Comment: @Barmar I've seen some websites using oauth with redirect on variable time so i'm guessing they have found a way

Comment: @Barmar No not in redirecting case. Not guaranteed there. You can test it to see

Comment: All I can imagine is that you're doing the local storage assignment in an asynchronous function, and the redirect is happening before the assignment.

Comment: Go to the main page of stack overflow, crack open your developer tools.  Plug this into your console: `localStorage.setItem('test', 'hi'); window.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62942684/making-sure-that-a-value-is-saved-in-localstorage-before-redirecting?noredirect=1#comment111307889_62942684';`  which will cause it to set the storage and navigate back to this page.  If you then try to get that localStorage value, it exists.

Comment: Another possiblity of the value not being there would be if the redirect goes to a different domain, in which case the value would not be returned as it is associated with the previous domain.

Comment: I just tried a test. I put `localStorage.setItem("testing", "this is a test");
window.location.href = "localgetter.html";` in `localsetter.html`.  I put `let value = localStorage.getItem("testing");
document.getElementById("output").innerText = value;` in `localgetter.html`

Comment: When I went to `localsetter.html`, it redirected to `localgetter.html` and displayed the message.

Comment: @Barmar It's Oauth redirection on another origin. That's when the problem happens

Comment: @thepowerlies As Taplar pointed out, local storage is per-domain. You can't set a variable for another origin.

Comment: @Barmar And as I said its an oauth redirect to login. It will redirect the user back

Comment: Then it should work. Once the local storage is saved, it stays there even if you redirect to a different domain. I'm not sure how to create a simple test case that proves this, though.

Comment: @Barmar Alright. Appreciate your effort anyway