# The i18nProvider returned a Promise for the messages of the default locale. react-admin

Tags: javascript, react-admin

**What you were expecting:** 
Set initial locale with value from `localStorage.getItem('locale_language');` instead of **`'en'`**.

```
import polyglotI18nProvider from 'ra-i18n-polyglot'; // react-admin 

const i18nProvider = polyglotI18nProvider(locale => {
    if (locale === 'ru') {
        return import('./i18n/ru').then(messages => messages.default);
    }
    return englishMessages;
}, 'en');
```

**What happened instead:**

But when I do this there is error `Error: The i18nProvider returned a Promise for the messages of the default locale (ru). Please update your i18nProvider to return the messages of the default locale in a synchronous way.`

**Related code:**

There is how I get value from localStore

```
export function getLocalLanguage(): string {
    let defaultLocalLanguage = 'en';
    const storedLanguage = localStorage.getItem('locale_language');
    if (storedLanguage !== null) {
        defaultLocalLanguage = storedLanguage;
    }
    return defaultLocalLanguage;
}
```

There is how I set initial local for `polyglotI18nProvider`

```
const i18nProvider = polyglotI18nProvider(locale => {
    if (locale === 'ru') {
        return import('./i18n/ru').then(messages => messages.default);
    }
    return englishMessages;
}, getLocalLanguage());
```

[Here is said localStorage is syncronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20231163/is-html5-localstorage-asynchronous) so there should be no problem then?

`resolveBrowserLocale` may be an alternative, but I need a more persistent way to store language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're setting the default locale to `'ru'` when pulling from localStorage, but your `import` for the `'ru'` strings is asynchronous.

From the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ra-i18n-polyglot#asynchronous-locale-change) for `ra-i18n-polyglot`:

> The messages for the default locale (used by react-admin for the initial render) must be returned in a synchronous way.

The [example](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/a7cb02fc7547861537ec0f1adf7dfc3da17edf2f/docs/Translation.md#using-the-browser-locale) they give suggests that if you want to dynamically resolve the *default* (= *initial*) locale, you need to import all possible languages synchronously:

```js
import englishMessages from 'ra-language-english';
import frenchMessages from 'ra-language-french';

const messages = {
    fr: frenchMessages,
    en: englishMessages,
};

const i18nProvider = polyglotI18nProvider(
    locale => messages[locale] ? messages[locale] : messages.en,
    resolveBrowserLocale()
);
```

Edit: more code

Comment: Yes, it solved this problem. I thought issue was with ```localStorage```. Now I return it  ```return russianMessages;```  instead of ```return import('./i18n/ru').then(messages => messages.default);```. Thank you.