# Loading image in jQuery promise freezes while browser is busy

Tags: jquery, loading, promise, busyindicator

I have the following code:

```
var self = this;
jQuery('#' + loadingAlert.id).promise()
          .done(() => self.showProgress())
          .done(window.setTimeout(() => self.someMethod(), 100));
          .done(() => self.hideProgress());
```

The someMethod function makes the browser so busy that it freezes the loading gif. Is there any work around for this so that my loading gif moves while the browser is busy (note: cannot click on anything as it is very busy);

Comment: `jQuery('#' + loadingAlert.id)` is redundant. just do `jQuery(loadingAlert)`

Comment: In modern browsers, you can use a webworker.

Comment: You have to show us what `someMethod` does.

Comment: `jQuery('#' + loadingAlert.id)` may be redundant. `jQuery(loadingAlert)` will suffice if `loadingAlert` is a reference to a DOM element.

Comment: What is `=>` all about?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Performance Long Running Tasks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864397/javascript-performance-long-running-tasks)

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: He seems to use CoffeeScript or ES harmony but has not understood it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In modern browsers, you can use a webworker. – Kevin B

I used webworker to fix this problem, so the heavy parsing is in the background and doesn't freeze  the browser as well.

Though it doesn't work in IE9 and other browsers mentioned [here](http://caniuse.com/webworkers), I just made a work around:

```
if (window['Worker']) { ... }
```

which means if it supports the webworker. Those that don't support the webworker hangs (still using my old code), but the browser versions which does work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any work around for this so that my loading gif moves while the browser is busy

No. You will have to change the `someMethod` function which causes the freeze to become asynchronous and do its work in smaller chunks.