# Google Chrome Average request time

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, optimization, time, average

On my project, I would like to optimize an ajax request and to know, on average, how many ms I have gained.

So, thanks to the Google Chrome network tab, I have the time of a request, something like that :

[image]

Is there a feature to have some stats about our request ? For example the average time.

If no, how to do that ?

Thanks !

Comment: You need to record the time of the request and the time of the success, then do math.

Comment: possible duplicate of [measure processing time of AJAX call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177451/measure-processing-time-of-ajax-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not too difficult to roll your own code in JavaScript.

```
var times = [];
var sum = 0;
var tries = 10
for(var i=0; i<tries; i++) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", window.location.href, false);
    xhr.onload = (function() {
        var time = (Date.now() - this.start);
        times.push(time);
        sum += time;
        console.log("#" + this.number + " " + time + "ms");
    }).bind(xhr);
    xhr.number = (i + 1);
    xhr.start = Date.now();
    xhr.send(null);
}
console.log("avg: " + (sum / tries) + "ms");
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to url: chrome://net-internals

[Description here](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/netlog)